# Two Bridged NICS Redhat VMWARE

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, ethernet

I have a laptop running Windows 7, and an instance of Redhat on VMWARE 12. My laptop only has 1 physical NIC, so I got a CableMatters 202023 USB to Fast Ethernet Adapter to get a second NIC.

I need to have the VMWARE Redhat client able to talk to two different networks through the two NICS.

On the Laptop internal NIC, I have a 172.18.0.X network
On the USB NIC I have a 172.19.0.X

I am using bridging settings in VMWARE to bridge the two together. Then in Linux I perform the following:

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth0 172.18.0.20 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0 down

ifconfig eth0:1 172.18.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:2 172.18.0.18 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:3 172.19.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:4 172.19.0.18 netmask 255.255.255.240

ifconfig eth0 up
```

The 172.18.0.X network works, but the 172.19.0.X network does not. I can't ping to anything.

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to "connect" the USB NIC into Linux and then add routes? Or can I keep Windows using it and rely on the bridged connection?

Comment: The USB device cannot be attachted to the Virtual Machin and the Host at the same time.  There is a reason your physical network adapter works though.

Comment: I don't understand when you have two physical NIC's then why you need to create or tag with virtual adapter of **eth0:3** or **eth0:4** with the first NICs interface.

Comment: Welcome to superuser, could accept your answer then it will not appear in 'unanswered questions' and help people using the site. Thanks for your question and answer and again welcome to superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

I used a network switch, wired both networks to the switch. (Disconnected the second NIC). Then in the host OS, Windows 7 I set up the NIC to have both 172.18.0.X and 172.19.0.X alternative IPs.

Then in the Linux VM I did the following:

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0

ifconfig eth0 172.18.0.30 netmask 255.255.255.240

ifconfig eth0 down

ifconfig eth0:1 172.18.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:2 172.18.0.18 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:3 172.19.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth0:4 172.19.0.18 netmask 255.255.255.240

ifconfig eth0 up
```